# FInd $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(i)$ and $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)$ and find GCD of $85$ and $1+13i$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

So for finding $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(i)$ I have that an ideal is the whole ring if it contains a unit. So ($i$) contains a unit,  namely $i$ as

$$(-i)(i)=1$$

thus $i$ is a unit forcing $(i)$ to be all of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ thus $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is the trivial ring.

For $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)$ I know $1+i=0$ so $i= -1$ and $-i= 1$ so we only have $1$ and $-1$ which is iso to $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is this correct?

And for dividing $85$ by $1+13i$ I know

$$\frac{85}{1+13i}=-6i$$

but I wanna know why we round the fractions $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{13}{2}$ down to $0$ and $6$ Then when I plug this for $q$ into

$$85=q(1+13i)+r$$
and solve for $r$ I get $7+6i$. where do I go from there do I divide $1+13i$ by $7+6i$ to show the next remainder is $0$

Cause that equals 1+i which means $r=0$ in the next step. So is the GCD just $$7+6i$$?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this post has been up for over 12 hours and no one has helped can someone comment if I’m on the right track or not

Comment: Why don't we multiply with $-7i$?

Answer (score 1):

You solved everything you asked but it is necessary to talk about the prime factorization of the Gaussian integers for a better solution for your last question.

Here, $85=(2+i)(2-i)(4+i)(4-i)$ and $1+13i=(2+i)(4+i)(1+i)$ are prime factorization of these numbers up to units, so upto units, $GCD(85,1+13i)=(2+i)(4+i)=7+6i$.

I learned these things today from : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#:~:text=Basic%20definitions,-The%20Gaussian%20integers&text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20Gaussian,is%20thus%20an%20integral%20domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#:%7E:text=Basic%20definitions,-The%20Gaussian%20integers&text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20Gaussian,is%20thus%20an%20integral%20domain).

It also says: Unfortunately, except in simple cases, the prime factorization is difficult to compute, and Euclidean algorithm leads to a much easier (and faster) computation. I think this is a simple case.

Comment: How did you so quickly realize that 85 is that and 1+13i is that?

Comment: $85=5\times 17$ and for such prime numbers the link says there are such products. For $1+13i$, I considered its norm $N(1+13i)=1+169=170=2\times 85$, and $2=-i(1+i)^2$ etc.

Comment: Stare at $13=6 \cdot 2 + 1$ and $\frac{13}2=6 + \frac12$ for a while. The important property here is that $0 \leq \vert r \vert < 2$.

Comment: $85=-6i(1+13i)+7+6i$...

Comment: How do we find non-trivial primes in a cylotomic field @CyclotomicField?